# @JsonDeserialize doesn't work when I put it above the method

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to custom deserialize incoming json to the field, but @JsonDeserialize is not working wheh I put it above the setter of the field I want to deserialize.

```
public class MyEntity {

@JsonProperty("identifier")
private String identifier;

@JsonDeserialize(using = IdentifierDeserializer.class)
public void setIdentifier(String identifier)
{
    this.identifier = identifier;
}
}
```

....

```
public class IdentifierDeserializer
    extends JsonDeserializer<String>
{
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException
    {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);

        final JsonNode entity = node.get("entity");
        return entity.get("id").asText();
    }
}
```

Im doing this via _restTemplate httpMessageConverter flow, just standar API calls, and no, it does not throw any exceptions, it just not invoked, because I this this with debug and my breakpoints left untouched.

```
 HttpEntity<T> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(entity, httpHeaders());
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Lists.newArrayList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));        
    _restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonConverter);
    return _restTemplate.exchange(url, method, httpEntity, MyEntity.class).getBody();
```

But @JsonDeserialize does work when I put it above the class. So what's the problem guys? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize a string? or you want to deserialize the class that contains ```identifier``` field? Elaborate more if possible on how you want this to work, how do you call this, and what you mean by "not working". Does it throw a runtime exception? Show an example of how you run this.

Comment: I added description. This is called by JacksonHttpMessageConverter via _restTemplate API calls flow, and during debug I dont see that my custom deserializer is invoked.

Comment: This works for me. You would have to post a sample of your json and how you are using `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: I added the sample I use.